# Push / Pull current branch

Tags: git, aptana

It is possible in aptana to push / pull only the current branch? I mean, if it is possible in the team menu, to configure it somehow so when i do a pull / push, only use the current branch.

thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The surest way to do this would be with EGit (that you would need to add to yuor Aptana setup, as illustrated in "[Getting Aptana Studio 3 working with GitHub on your Windows PC](http://yllus.com/2010/11/06/getting-aptana-studio-3-working-with-github-on-your-windows-pc/)").
[This thread details it](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/716981/):

> Egit has its own way to handle this, which might be overriding your config setting.
>   Either that or jgit doesn't support this configuration option yet -- that situation came up earlier with `merge.ff`.
>
> The EGit preference can be set from `Team -> Remote -> Configure Push to Upstream...`
>   The default is to push everything, I think.
>   You can restrict it to 'master', or whatever specific branches you prefer, in the dialog that will pop up.
>   Similarly for fetch, via and `Team -> Remote -> Configure Fetch from UpStream...`
>   I don't know if either of these supports 'current'.

Indeed, pushing only the *current* branch might not be directly supported by an official release of EGit just yet: See [bug 352381](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=352381).
In other word, EGit/JGit might not take into account the [git config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) "**`push.default`**":

> `current` - push the current branch to a branch of the same name.

Comment: For the current branch you can use HEAD as source reference.

Comment: @dunni: Excellent, so Egit does support it that way (using `HEAD`). But I don't think it does follow the `push.default` config yet.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I'm unable to comment on VonC's answer as I don't have the required rep yet.

EGit can be configured to push only the current branch by removing all push preferences from it's git config file. This must be the default EGit behaviour if no push config is specified. Here's how to do this:

- Go to the Git Repositories view.
- Right-click on the repo you want to configure.
- Select 'Properties' from the context menu.
- In the Key | Value input area, delete all push specs within the **origin** heading. There's probably 2 of them, along the lines of `refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*` and `refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*`).